# Holding ILR and having a child with British citizenship, can I be British before 12 months

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-citizens

I have an indefinite leave to remain in UK since March 2016. I have children born in UK whom I will register as British citizens. If my children have British citizenship, can I apply for the British citizenship before I finish 12 months holding ILR? I have a job offer outside the UK that starts in October 2016 and, if I stay till March 2017, I may lose it.

Answer (score 1):

No. A descendant child's status is not taken into consideration for adult citizenship applications.